# Why is realpath() only working with certain folders?

Tags: php, plesk, realpath

I am using PHP's `realpath()` function, and want to know why I get the following output:

```
bool(false)
string(48) "/var/www/vhosts/website.co.uk/httpdocs"
bool(false)
string(48) "/var/www/vhosts/website.co.uk/httpdocs"
```

when running this script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
header('content-type: text/plain');

var_dump(realpath('/var/www/vhosts/website.co.uk/application'));
var_dump(realpath('/var/www/vhosts/website.co.uk/httpdocs'));
var_dump(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
var_dump(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../httpdocs'));

exit;
```

with these file permissions:

```
drwxr-x---  5 username  psaserv 4096 Jul 16 08:22 application
drwxr-x--- 10 username  psaserv 4096 Jul 16 13:34 httpdocs
```

**Note:**

- This is a Plesk system
- Script runs as `apache` user
- `apache` user is part of the `psaserv` group

Comment: delete application and re create again

Comment: No it's not - nothing in that file path is a symlink

Comment: Akam: Why, out of interest? I have tested this by creating a folder called `test` and the same issue occurs

Comment: so realpath only true for httpdocs? or its only fails on application?

Comment: Seems to only be true for httpdocs - I've tried on other folders (that I didn't create myself - such as `statistics`) with `x` group permission and it's still false.

Comment: I think it's just related to script execution permission (Or generally file and folder permission)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Plesk and openbase_dir restrictions

Unless plesk has changed in the past few years - [it sets open_basedir restrictions](http://forum.parallels.com/pda/index.php/t-97187.html) such that you can only access the `httpdocs` folder:

> The default open_basedir settings gives you the ability to write to 2 locations for each website. There should be no reason to write to any other folder. [...]
>
> - /tmp
> - /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs

As such if a request attempts to read from/write to any other location - it won't be able to do so, hence `realpath` will return false for any location outside the `httpdocs` folder.

---

*if you would like to see the script linked in the referenced forum post, it moved and can be found here: [unplesk](https://github.com/AD7six/scripts/blob/master/unplesk).*

Comment: You're correct. I discovered this a few hours after my post , actually asked about it on the Plesk forum (http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?289085-Subscription-PHP-settings-(open_basedir)-ignored&p=693273#post693273). I will update my question to reflect what I've found.

Comment: Actually scrap that - the reason I was having trouble was seemingly a Plesk bug - where the service plan was getting overridden by the subscription level PHP settings (which were set to something by default instead of just `default`) - but now it's working perfectly, so your answer is in fact correct on its own :)